# Data.IntMap vs Data.Sequence in Haskell (Haskell Collections)

Tags: haskell, collections

What is the main difference between `Data.Sequence` / `Seq a` and `Data.IntMap` / `IntMap a` in Haskell? From everything I've read, they both offer a fast *cons* function, *fast random access*, and *fast random update*. What's the difference?

For context, I need all of these (fast *cons*, *fast random access*, and *fast random update*).

Which should I choose?

Comment: What implementation do you have for cons for IntMap?  IntMap indexes don't "shift over."

Answer (score 3):

A `Seq` stores something for every index between 0 and some number. An `IntMap` stores something for some but not all `Int` values. This is a big conceptual difference with obvious consequences for space usage—if your data are sparse, you probably don't want a dense representation. Cons and snoc are somewhat cheaper for `Seq` than for `IntMap`, I'd expect, though they have different meanings, while random access is significantly slower. It sounds like you might be interested in what Okasaki calls a "random access list", but between `Seq` and `IntMap`, you'd best analyze your specific algorithm and benchmark.

Comment: Random access into `Seq` is going to be somewhat slower than `IntMap` on most occasions, but it's still sub-linear.  That's not nothing.

Comment: @Carl, for sure. Louis Wasserman's point that cons and snoc do different things is probably more important in the end.